# Can we determine if $y(x)=\frac {c-x}{x+1}$ has any strictly positive integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The equation is as follows:

$$y=\frac {c-x}{x+1}$$

Where $c$ is a positive, even integer.

Is it possible to determine whether there are any positive integer solutions different than $x=0$?

Some examples:

$c=14$; $x=2$; $y=4$.

$c=10$; NO POSITIVE INTEGER SOLUTION

$c=20$; $x=2$; $y=6$.

$c=44$; $x=4$; $y=8$.

$c=76$; $x=6$; $y=10$.

Comment: What are the unknows here? Only x?

Comment: What is $y$? Is it integer or real?

Comment: How is $x=0$ a solution if $y\neq c$ (I am assuming $y$ is fixed?)

Comment: In what sense is this linear?

Comment: Say $c=11, y=5$, you get $x=1$.. So, perhaps there are some restrictions for $y, c$?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. If $c$ is odd then $y$ will be an integer when $x=2$, Please [edit] the question to clarify. Perhaps show some examples.

Comment: @dmtri x and y are unknown

Comment: @Andrei both y and x should be integers

Comment: You ask if it is possible .... and then give examples.  Those examples show that of course it is possible.

Comment: @fleablood yes, but they are specific examples I calculated for specific c values; The question is whether or not it's possible to extend that to any given number c. Say, I have c=120: is it possible, without undergoing a trial and error process, to know whether or not it has an integer solution?

Comment: $y = \frac {c-x}{x+1}\implies y(x+1) + x= c\implies y(x+1)  + (x+1) = (y+1)(x+1) = c+1$.  If $c+1= mk; 1 < m;1 < k$ is composite then $y=m-1;x=k-1$ will be a solution.  If $c+1$ is prime then either $x=0$ (and $y=c$) or $y = 0$ (and $x=c$).  [basically this is John Omielan's answer]

Comment: Alternatively .... $x + 1 |c-x \iff x+1|(c-x) + (x+1)=c+1$.  So $x$ can be one less than any factor of $c+1$.  If $c+1$ is prime that requires $x$ to be $0$ or $c$.  But if $c+1$ is not prime $x = k-1$ for any $k|c+1$ will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** You have

$$y = \frac{c - x}{x + 1} = \frac{c + 1 - 1 - x}{x + 1} = \frac{c + 1 - (1 + x)}{x + 1} = \frac{c + 1}{x + 1} - 1$$

Next, consider how whether or not $c + 1$ is prime, e.g., where $c = 10$, affects the existence of positive integer solutions for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You are right, it all boils down to whether or not c+1 is prime: if it isn't prime, there will always be an integer solution different than x=0. The equation above is something I came up with by trying to look at primes through the lens of modular arithmetics - I've got to dig deeper!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different wording than John Omielan's answer (but same idea) may make this more intuitively clearer.

$y = \frac {c-x}{x+1}$ will have solutions when $x+1|c-x$.

And $x+1|c-x \iff x+1|(c-x)+(x+1)= c+1$.

So for any $k|d=c+1$, we will have solutions $x = k-1$ (and $y = \frac {c-(k-1)}{(k-1)+1}=\frac {(c+1)-k}k = \frac dk -1$)

However if $d=c+1$ is prime we either $x= 0$ or $x = d-1=c$ (in which case $y=0$).

Answer (score 0):

It was not perfectly clear to me whether this was a question about suitable $x$ (any solutions other than $x=0$?) or about suitable $c$ (listing various $c$ for which $x,y$ could be found). I provide an answer about $x$, and the implications for $c$.

$y$ is an integer when $c=k(x+1)+x$, viz: $y=\frac{k(x+1)+x-x}{x+1}=k$.

However, since $x$ and $x+1$ have different parities, $c$ cannot be even when $x$ is odd. When $x$ is even, $k=2n$ must be even for $c=2n(x+1)+x$ to be even. In that case, $y=\frac{2n(x+1)+x-x}{x+1}=2n$.

In sum, solutions exist for all $x$ and $y$ being any even integers; $c$ is limited to being of the form $c=2n(x+1)+x$ for any particular chosen $x$.